# PHP try-catch block not catching issues as expected

Tags: php, exception

I have the following code that is suppose to work (the exception must be caught) but it is not.

```
<?php

class Entertainment {
}

class Clown extends Entertainment{
}

class Job {
}

function handleEntertainment(Entertainment $en, callable $callback = NULL){
    try{
        print("Handling " . get_class($en) . " is fun");
        if($callback !== NULL){
            $callback();
       }/*else {
            print("<br />" . "Function must be given!");
        }*/
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo("Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . " Line: " . $e->getLine());
    }
}

$functionCallback = function(){
    print("<br />". " I am a function");
}

?>
```

This is the test file

```
<?php
require_once("manyclasses.php");

try{
    handleEntertainment(new Clown());
    handleEntertainment(new Job());
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo("Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . " Line: " . $e->getLine());
}


?>
```

The second call  `handleEntertainment(new Job());`   should throw an Exception and must be caught but it is not working that way. What I get is

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to handleEntertainment() must be an instance of Entertainment, instance of Job given, called in ................
```

I tried to search for answers here but the posts I read makes me more confused. Some people said WARNINGS and ERRORS are not caught as exceptions.

My understanding is that warnings and errors are also exceptions and the try and catch block must be able to catch them.

Why is it not working and why are the warnings and errors not Exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `Catchable Fatal Error` are errors that leave the engine in unstable state so the execution should be aborted. 
Think about it: after a "normal" exception you can, sometimes, recover program execution flow whereas under this circumstance is preferable to abort the execution.

If you want however, you can define [your own error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and let the execution keep going